# Spring security - Call custom authentication provider from custom login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a custom login page (SecureLogin.jsp)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="userName" name="userName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="password" name="password"/><td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit"  value="submit" action="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Spring security.xml is as follows :

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/security/SecureLogin.jsp*" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/security/showCustomPage*" access="hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOM')" />
    <form-login 
            login-page="/security/SecureLogin.jsp" 
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/security/showError.jsp"  />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider  ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>

</authentication-manager>
```

I want to my Login call to be processed by the customAuthenticationProvider.
But when submitting the login credentials, it is showing 
`Error 404: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 404`
The app Url for the above error is :

```
http://localhost:9081/app/security/j_spring_security_check
```

I am new to Spring and Spring security. Any help is much appreciated.
Also if there is a better way to control login, please do suggest.

**EDIT** : Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>app</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

<!-- Spring Entries Start  -->
    <listener>
         <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/config/context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/config/dispatcher-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/security/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security Entries start -->  
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <!-- Spring Security Entries end -->

<!-- Spring Entries End -->

</web-app>
```

context.xml

```
<import resource="security.xml" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.demo" />
<context:annotation-config />
```

dispatcher-config.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.endpoint" />
    <context:annotation-config />
```

Comment: which spring version? and if it is spring boot?

Comment: Spring - 3.2 and Spring security - 3.0.5. It is not a spring boot project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution : I upgraded spring security to 3.1.7 and changed the security.xml

```
<http pattern="/security/**" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="customAuthenticationManager" >
        <intercept-url pattern="/security/SecureLogin.jsp*" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/security/doSecureLogin*" access="permitAll" /> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/security/j_spring_security_check*" access="permitAll"  />
        <intercept-url pattern="/security/Login.jsp/**" access="permitAll" />       
        <intercept-url pattern="/security/showCustomPage*" access="hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOM')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/security/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_WELCOME')" />
        <form-login 
        login-page="/security/SecureLogin.jsp" 
        login-processing-url="/security/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-failure-url="/security/showError.jsp"  />

    </http>
    <http pattern="/api/**" auto-config="true" security="none" />


    <authentication-manager alias="customAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider  ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/> 
    </authentication-manager>
```

In the http tag I gave the reference to my authentication-manager in which my custom-authentication-provider is defined. Now on click of submit, the custom-authentication-provider is called.
Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

please try changing the name attribute of input fields for username and password like below (for **username** it is going to be **j_username** and for **password** please use **j_password**):-

```
<form action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="userName" name="j_username"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="password" name="j_password"/><td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit"  value="submit" action="submit">
</form>
```

if you want to change the input field's parameter name, then you can do something like below in the `<form-login>` with attributes - `username-parameter` and `password-parameter` respectively for the **username** and **password**

Upon initialization of a DispatcherServlet, the framework looks for a file named `[servlet-name]-servlet.xml` in the WEB-INF directory of your web application and create the beans defined there, overriding the definitions of any beans defined with the same name in the global scope. please rename your dispatcher servlet to `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

Comment: The file name should be dispatcher-servlet.xml only

Comment: Refer link here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch15s02.html

Comment: I have a requirement to use dispatcherServlet only for urls with /api/* and /security/* . Since this is going to be integrated with a struts project.

Comment: ok in you form try - <form action="<c:url value='/security/j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>

Comment: Upon initialization of a DispatcherServlet, the framework looks for a file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory of your web application and create the beans defined there, overriding the definitions of any beans defined with the same name in the global scope. please rename your dispatcher servlet to dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: I changed the dispatcher - servlet name and added the /security/ in jsp, but still getting the same error.

Comment: ok last thing to do - remove - `<init-param>` section from the `<servlet-name>dispatcher....`

Comment: and I hope you are not trying to access the url directly like - http://localhost:9081/app/security/j_spring_security_check

because the url is going to be of POST type not GET type

Comment: When i removed the init-param i got the following error
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]`. My dispatcher-servlet resides in resources/config/ location.

Comment: In regards to your previous question, I am not trying to access the url directly. I am using the login page and trying to move forward from there.

Comment: the url `http://localhost:9081/app/security/j_spring_security_check` is of POST type, you will not able to directly in browser

Comment: Still the same error. url after submit click : `http://localhost:9081/app/security/j_spring_security_check`

Comment: is your app deployed under the context /app?

Comment: yes. I have configured the SecureLogin.jsp through dispatcherServlet itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing **login-processing-url**

from

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/security/SecureLogin.jsp*" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/security/showCustomPage*" access="hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOM')" />
    <form-login 
            login-page="/security/SecureLogin.jsp" 
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/security/showError.jsp"  />
</http>
```

to

```
<http>
<intercept-url pattern="/security/SecureLogin.jsp*" filters="none" />
<intercept-url pattern="/security/showCustomPage*" access="hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOM')" />
<form-login 
        login-page="/security/SecureLogin.jsp" 
        login-processing-url="/security/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-url="/security/showError.jsp"  />
```